# Phalcon's hasMany doesn't work correctly

Tags: phalcon, phalcon-orm

Can't figure out why this simple code doesn't work:

```
$pack = new Pack();
$pack->name = 'A pack';

$packItems = array();

$packItem = new PackItem();
$packItem->pack = $pack;
$packItem->name = 'First item in the pack';
$packItems[] = $packItem;

$packItem = new PackItem();
$packItem->pack = $pack;
$packItem->name = 'Second item in the pack';
$packItems[] = $packItem;

$pack->packItems = $packItems;
$pack->save();
```

The Pack model:

```
$this->hasMany('id', 'PackItem', 'packItemId', array(
    'alias' => 'packItems'
));
```

And the PackItem model:

```
$this->belongsTo('packId', 'Pack', 'id', array(
    'alias' => 'pack'
));
```

After I try to run this code it ends on error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Maximum function nesting level of '256' reached, aborting!
```

The log file is full of code like this:

```
...
PHP  39. Phalcon\\Mvc\\Model->save()
PHP  40. Phalcon\\Mvc\\Model->_postSaveRelatedRecords()
PHP  41. Phalcon\\Mvc\\Model->save()
PHP  42. Phalcon\\Mvc\\Model->_preSaveRelatedRecords()
...
```

I don't have more ideas how it doesn't work. I use Phalcon 3.0 and It seems to me it is a bug. What do you think?

Comment: You use `packItemId` and `packId` in your relations, shouldn't these be the same?

Comment: Yea, most likely they should.

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you mean. PackId refers to Pack model and packItemId to PackItem model. How relations should look like in your opinion?

Comment: Hey @Adam, your question has accepted answer in the forum: https://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/15273/hasmany-doesnt-work-correctly-maximum-function-nesting-level-err Maybe you should answer your question and solve it or just delete the question.